# CSS unable to align vert/horz an img positioned in absolute

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following issue, where I want to move the logo to the position shown in the picture

[image]

Im able to move the image around using properties like:

```
    .img-logo{
      display:flex;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      left: 50%

    }
```

But the point is, those are not exact values, I dont know how to do it with exact values

Because if I use

```
    .img-logo{
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

The image wont even move

The htlm is like this

```
 <div class="main">

             <form class='login-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <img alt="image" src={brand} width="60" height="60" class="img-logo"/>

                <p class='lf--upper-text' >Welcome to app</p>

                <div class="flex-row">
                    <label class="lf--label" htmlFor="email">
                        <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="12px" height="13px">
```

where .main

```
   .main { height: 100%; }
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
```

and .login-form

```
    .login-form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;

  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    width: 50vw;
    max-width: 15em;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you simply update with following css. for the logo alignment.

`.main{ position:relative;}

.img-logo { 
position:absolute; 
top:0;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%);
}`

Comment: @Yudiz_Webdesign you solution actually manages to center it horizontally, but I still dont know how to bring it to that middle position vertically so it will mantain it when resizing the screen

Comment: What we understand is that, you only want to manage logo position on top with -50% height of the logo in the form right? so can you give .login-form {position: relative;}. it will align logo to horizontally center as well as vertically -50% of logo height to top of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it

```
   <div class="flex-row img-logo">
                    <img  src={brand} width="60" height="60" class="img-logo-in" />
                 </div>
```

css

```
    .img-logo{
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 20%

}

.img-logo-in{ 
  position:absolute;

  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%); }
```